# Materializecss Modal Error in IE11 - Argument not optional

Tags: internet-explorer-11, materialize

I am using v1.0.0-alpha.1 release of Materializecss and having trouble in initializing modals in IE11. Its giving Error - **Argument not optional**

When I am accessing the docs here at http://next.materializecss.com/modals.html page, it is also showing same error and modals are not working. Please see the screenshot below -

[image: IE11 Console screenshot]

Browser - Internet Explorer Version 11.726.15063.0

Comment: Same issue with autocomplete and datepicker. Working in chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is also there in alpha 2 release. But I got the workaround till this is officially fixed.

Make a copy of material.js file and find

```
implementation.createHTMLDocument()
```

Replace with

```
implementation.createHTMLDocument(null)
```